# What is the proper way to read n files using shell script?

Tags: linux, shell

There are 2 ways to read "n" files:

```
cat *.*
```

and

```
#!/bin/sh
fmount=/opt/insiteone/fuse-mount/ifm/IFM-TestData/*

for myFiles in $fmount
do
   cat $myFiles  2>&1 | tee -a readFile.log &
done
```

What is the proper way to read it and why? If the first is fine, then why people try the second option (the longer form)?

**Added:** Also i would like to know how the internals of each behave, since we are basically calling this from fuse callbacks.

Comment: The two commands don't even remotely do the same thing.

Comment: Note that file name extensions are not required in unixy systems, so if you want to refer to all files, then you shouldn't use `*.*` -- just use `*` by itself.

Comment: The second one is looking for paths that contain the case-insensitive string "file" in them, whereas the first is looking for filenames that contain a dot in them.

Answer (score 0):

The second is chosen when some form of error trapping needs to occur, and to look for specific content before catting the file. Also, in the second, it's output to the terminal and a log, rather than just the terminal as in the first.

Answer (score 0):

The second one incorrectly tries to parse the output of `ls`. It would be better written as

```
#!/bin/sh
fmount=/opt/insiteone/fuse-mount/ifm/IFM-TestData/

cat "$fmount"/*file* > readFile.log &
```

Whether you use the first or second depends heavily on what you want to do, since (as already pointed out) they do two different things. (Plus, after re-writing the second one, it's no longer that different from the first.)

Comment: My purpose is to know how the internals of each works, basically we have a fuse-mounted directory, and cat will do an `open( )` but how does both versions vary in that case?

Comment: As far as `cat` is concerned, the only difference is in which files are passed to `cat` to open. In terms of the scripts, they do two different things, and are not comparable. Give two pieces of code that are written differently, but do the *exact* same thing, and you can make comparisons.

Comment: I have modified the code, now do you agree the internals of both should work identical?

Comment: The first one calls `cat` with multiple arguments. The second calls `cat` multiple times, each one receiving one argument. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: I edited my question with an `Added` stuff. So do you think the fuse callbacks behave identically in both? Forget about the `tee` or the logging part to cat.

Comment: My opinion? As long as fuse is working properly, there should be no differences. The point of a file system is to provide a uniform interface to reading and writing files, so that application code doesn't need to know those details.